# ContentView ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to auto wire my view model to my content view in Xamarin forms using this syntax:

```html
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="APP.Views.PostEntryView"
             x:Name="postEntryView">
```

the name of my view model is PostEntryViewViewModel but it does not doing anything

Is there any way to auto wire a content view to a view model, how I have to register it in the container??

Answer (score 1):

Rename your ViewModel to `PostEntryViewModel`. The default naming would be as follows:

```
View              ViewModel
SomeView          SomeViewModel
SomePage          SomePageViewModel
Something         SomethingViewModel
```

Alternatively you may follow something like the function the [Container Extensions](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Unity.Forms/UnityExtensions.cs#L136) use to register a specific View and ViewModel